# Inserting a UIWebView within a UITableViewCell for playing animated GIFs

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiwebview

I am working on a table view where I want to include animated gifs. So I am trying to use a `UIWebView`. The `IBOutlet` on the the connecting data are:

```
@IBOutlet weak var infoLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
```

Inside the table view controller:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell


    cell.infoLabel.text = productNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: productImages[indexPath.row])


    return cell
}
```

`productNames` and the `productImages` variables are arrays, where images and titles are specified. Is there an equivalent type that you can assign the `UIWebView` (and therefore I can set up an array to feed the cell the animated GIF)?

Comment: Do you want to insert a web view into *each* cell? The performance can become really poor because of that.

Comment: No, just a local animated GIF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to play animated Gif's, why don't you try Flipboard's animated Image component for iOS.

> **FLAnimatedImage is a performant animated GIF engine for iOS:**
>
> Plays multiple GIFs simultaneously with a playback speed comparable to
>   desktop browsers
>  Honors variable frame delays
>  Behaves
>   gracefully under memory pressure
>  Eliminates delays or blocking
>   during the first playback loop
>  Interprets the frame delays of
>   fast GIFs the same way modern browsers do

https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage

Comment: I'm using swift vs. Object-C. But that does look like a better solution than what I'm attempting.

Comment: ObjectiveC code can be used in swift. It might be more efficient than using UIWebViews

Comment: :) Its fine. everyone was a noob once.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to use FLAnimatedImage (and have the time constraint of wrapping up this project). Based on the two responses I received about concerns about how my original idea would be too resource intensive, I decided to go in a different direction. Although all my images are animated GIFs, I decided to use UIImage.animationImages.

I converted the frames in the animated GIF to individual PNG files (Photoshop has a script that will do this). Set up an array of the individual PNGs like:

```
var animationImages = [UIImage(named:"a1.png")!, UIImage(named:"a2.png")!, UIImage(named:"a3.png")!, UIImage(named:a4.png")!,UIImage(named:"a5.png")!]
var animationImages2 = [UIImage(named:"b1.png")!, UIImage(named:"b2.png")!, UIImage(named:"b3.png")!, UIImage(named:b4.png")!,UIImage(named:"b5.png")!]
var animationImages3 = [UIImage(named:"c1.png")!, UIImage(named:"c2.png")!, UIImage(named:"c3.png")!, UIImage(named:c4.png")!,UIImage(named:"c5.png")!] //etc.
```

In override func tableView, where you specify the row object information:

```
cell.imageView.animationImages = findArray(indexPath.row) //findArray() is the func that I set up to return the associated image animation array
cell.imageView.animationDuration = 3
cell.imageView.startAnimating()
```

The findArray():

```
func findArray(theRowNumber:Int) -> NSArray{
    switch theRowNumber{
    case 0:
        return imageAnimation
    case 1:
        return imageAnimation2
    case 2:
        return imageAnimation3 //etc.
    default:
        return imageAnimation
    }
```

Probably not the most efficient way to accomplish this, but it works! :) With more experience in Web (including Flash), I wish Apple would just effin support animated GIF in the UIImage.